# Variable value not set in ssh -X

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh

I am Oracle DBA and i am doing some scripting to check if database is live or not on our large number of servers.

I am trying to set value to variable in ssh -X e.g

```
[oracle@proddb02]$ DB_STAT=`ssh -X  proaddb01 'ps -ef | grep pmon | grep -v grep' | awk '{ print $8 }'`

[oracle@proddb02]$ echo $DB_STAT
ora_pmon_pconn01
```

Above example works perfectly but as i am using ssh command i cannot loop using while as it exit at the first line file which include list of the servers.
so i have to add /dev/null to the command so that it should not exit the loop. but this does not set the variable value.
When i echo the variable it gives nothing.

```
[oracle@proddb02]$ DB_STAT=`ssh -X  proddb01 'ps -ef | grep pmon | grep -v grep' | awk '{ print $8 }'</dev/null`
[oracle@proddb02]$ echo $DB_STAT

[oracle@proddb02]$ echo $DB_STAT
```

The loop code is

```
[oracle@proddb02]$cat test.sh

while read line
do
INST_VAR=`echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }'`
HOST_VAR=`echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }'`
SERVER_NAME=$HOST_VAR
INSTANCE_NAME=$INST_VAR
DB_STAT=`ssh -X  proaddb01 'ps -ef | grep pmon | grep -v grep' | awk '{ print $8 }'`
echo $DB_STAT
done < host_list.lst
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The [useless use of `grep`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep) is easy enough to fix; `ps -ef | awk '/[p]mon/{print $8}'`

Comment: And with `while read INST_VAR HOST_VAR _; do` ... you can avoid those pesky assignments at the top of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
DB_STAT=`ssh -X  proaddb01 "ps -ef | awk '/[p]mon/'{ print $8 }"`
```

Here you use:

- `//` to filter the input stream (like grep but witj awk);
- the trick with `[p]grep` to exclude the same line from ps (because `[p]grep` string will not be found with `[p]grep` template).